# ChromeDriver not logging

Tags: c#, google-chrome, logging, selenium-chromedriver, .net-4.6.1

I am starting my selenium-driven headless chrome like this:

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions();

    options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;

    options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
    options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
    options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-web-security");
    options.AddArgument("--allow-insecure-localhost");
    options.AddArgument("--allow-running-insecure-content");
    options.AddArgument("--acceptInsecureCerts=true");
    options.AddArgument("--proxy-server='direct://'");
    options.AddArgument("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
    options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
    options.AddArgument("--incognito");
    options.AddArgument("--headless");
    options.AddArgument("--log-level=ALL");
    options.AddArgument("log-path=c:\\chromedriver.log");

    options.SetLoggingPreference(OpenQA.Selenium.LogType.Driver, OpenQA.Selenium.LogLevel.All);

    var svc = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    svc.Port = RandomHelper.Randomiser.Next(29700, 29900);

    Context.Driver = new ChromeDriver(svc, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

However, after running (and seeing successful test output - failing and passing tests) I see no file at `c:\chromedriver.log`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really frustrating developing with Selenium, but found how to log with ChromeDriver:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;

options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArgument("--disable-web-security");
options.AddArgument("--allow-insecure-localhost");
options.AddArgument("--allow-running-insecure-content");
options.AddArgument("--acceptInsecureCerts=true");
options.AddArgument("--proxy-server='direct://'");
options.AddArgument("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.AddArgument("--incognito");
options.AddArgument("--headless");
options.AddArgument("--log-level=ALL");
options.AddArgument("log-path=c:\\chromedriver.log");

options.SetLoggingPreference(OpenQA.Selenium.LogType.Driver, OpenQA.Selenium.LogLevel.All);

var svc = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
svc.Port = RandomHelper.Randomiser.Next(29700, 29900);

svc.LogPath = @"c:\chromedriver.log";
svc.EnableVerboseLogging = true;

options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Client, LogLevel.All);
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Profiler, LogLevel.All);
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Server, LogLevel.All);

Context.Driver = new ChromeDriver(svc, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

Comment: You have twice the line: `options.SetLoggingPreference(OpenQA.Selenium.LogType.Driver, OpenQA.Selenium.LogLevel.All);
`
is same as `options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);`